# com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Invalid value: {"value":"640.0n","type":"Big Number"} for expected type: DOUBLE

Tags: json, parsing, gson, protocol-buffers

I am parsing the json response but everytime i get this error message not sure how to fix it
Loading JavaScript to validate ECMA262 regular expression in JsonSchema because java.util.regex package in Java does not match ECMA262

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Invalid value: {"value":"640.0n","type":"Big Number"} for expected type: DOUBLE
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.parseFieldValue(JsonFormat.java:1964)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeField(JsonFormat.java:1662)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeMessage(JsonFormat.java:1493)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1451)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.parseFieldValue(JsonFormat.java:2011)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeField(JsonFormat.java:1662)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeMessage(JsonFormat.java:1493)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1451)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.parseFieldValue(JsonFormat.java:2011)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeRepeatedField(JsonFormat.java:1726)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeField(JsonFormat.java:1658)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeMessage(JsonFormat.java:1493)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1451)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.parseFieldValue(JsonFormat.java:2011)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeRepeatedField(JsonFormat.java:1726)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeField(JsonFormat.java:1658)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeMessage(JsonFormat.java:1493)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1451)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.parseFieldValue(JsonFormat.java:2011)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeRepeatedField(JsonFormat.java:1726)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeField(JsonFormat.java:1658)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeMessage(JsonFormat.java:1493)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1451)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.parseFieldValue(JsonFormat.java:2011)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeRepeatedField(JsonFormat.java:1726)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeField(JsonFormat.java:1658)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeMessage(JsonFormat.java:1493)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1451)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.parseFieldValue(JsonFormat.java:2011)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeRepeatedField(JsonFormat.java:1726)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeField(JsonFormat.java:1658)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.mergeMessage(JsonFormat.java:1493)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1451)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.merge(JsonFormat.java:1333)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$Parser.merge(JsonFormat.java:473)type here
```

com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Invalid value: {"value":"640.0n","type":"Big Number"} for expected type: DOUBLE

It should parse the json response correctly

Comment: The JSON doesn't correspond to a Protocol Buffer schema `value` of type `double`. If you were to create a test `Message` with `double value`, and use `640.0`, as the value of `value`, you'd get `{"value":640}` as the JSON marshaled message. Instead, your JSON appears to contain a `value` of type `string` and a descriptor for the type called `type` (also of type `string`) that may describe the value's type as `Big Number`.

Comment: Without any description of the application or the protocol buffer schema, it's difficult to provide help.